# Custom font not showing up spritekit?

Tags: ios, xcode, fonts, sprite-kit

I am trying to install a custom font for my spritekit project and I followed the directions exactly as it explain on [the apple documentation page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/text_display_and_fonts/adding_a_custom_font_to_your_app). My font shows up if I add a label in the storyboard and select it from the dropdown, but for some reason when I try to set the font programmatically I get the error:

```
SKLabelNode: "Players-Bold" font not found.
```

I'm setting the font like this:

```
scoreLabel.fontName = "Players-Bold"
```

Also, when I add a label to the storyboard and set its font to my custom font, then add the code above to my score label, the font shows up correctly, but when I delete the label from the storyboard, I get the error again.

Like I said, I know the font is installed correctly because I am able to select it in the storyboard, and I know the name of the font is correct because I followed the apple documentation page to find the proper name. What else could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Did you add it to your info.plist?

Comment: I did add it and it does work when I set the font in the storyboard, just not programmatically.

Comment: Yeah the storyboard does something a little different.  Are you using the correct font name?  I remember there was a different name I has to use for my fonts then what I thought it was,  I can’t remember how I got to it though.

Comment: I installed the font on my computer and then opened it using Font Book to make sure I am using the correct name. What's confusing to me is I can set my SKLabelNode's font programmatically and then add a separate label in the storyboard and set its font to my custom font also, and both the storyboard label and the SKLabelNode I set up programmatically will show up correctly. But then when I delete only the label I added in the storyboard, the SKLabelNode I set up programmatically stops working even though I didn't change anything about its code.

Comment: Is the font being packaged into the app?  Check your build settings. Maybe the font is being embedded into the xib when you add it via storyboard

Comment: How do I check it in the build settings? I did add the font to the Copy Bundle Resources section of Build Phases, but I'm not sure how Build Settings works.

Answer (score 0):

try doing it like this

```
let customFont = UIFont(name: "Custom Font Name", size: UIFont.systemFontSize)
let customLabel = UILabel()
customLabel.font = customFont
```

Comment: Is there no way to do it using SKLabelNode? I want to avoid using UIKit if there is a way to accomplish everything with just SpriteKit

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was just stupid. The reason the fonts weren't loading properly is because I was adding them to the *AppTests* info.plist and not the info.plist in the main directory. For some reason adding them into the Tests directory's info.plist makes them show up in the dropdown in the storyboard, but it obviously doesn't work for adding the fonts programmatically.

Once I added the fonts into the correct info.plist everything worked as intended.